# Адаптивность дизайна в Android

Tags: android

У меня кнопки адаптируются по ширине под разные экраны, но не по высоте. Вот код xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Как мне сделать адаптацию этих кнопок по высоте?

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите получить. Кнопки высотой во весь экран?

Comment: Ну например если на 5-ти дюймовом экране кнопка выглядит квадратной, то на большей или меньшей диагонали она уже прямоугольная. Я хочу чтобы кнопка выглядела одинаково квадратной на каждом экране. В моем коде она растягивается или сужается по ширине, в зависимости от экрана, а по высоте она остается такой же, т.е. на большом экране ее высота маленькая, а на малом экране ее высота огромная.

Comment: Оно так и не должно работать. Чтобы сделать квадратной - надо или свою вьюху писать, в ней определяя размеры сторон вручную или использовать ConstraintLayout - там, вроде, можно назначить высоту соответственно ширине кнопки.

Comment: в этом коде нет никакой адаптации по ширине.